# adding new datasource to an existing RRD

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I have few 100s of rrds and i want to add 5 extra datasource to all of those rrds.

1. Is it advisable to do so
2. Whats the best way and the fastest way to do it

-- **Soln** --

**David OBrien replied in the mailing list**

after searching the archives ( which you should have done first ) and googling I found several people using this...

with perl. Install RRD:Simple

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl 

use strict; 
use RRD::Simple (); 

my $rrd = RRD::Simple->new(); 
my $rrdfile=$ARGV[0]; 
my $source=$ARGV[1]; 
my $type=$ARGV[2]; 
chomp($type); 
$rrd->add_source($rrdfile, $source => $type);
```

usage:

```
./addSource.pl file.rrd ds GAUGE
```

or whatever the type is..

Enjoy.

Comment: you should really add David's solution as an *answer* to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

use rrddump and rrdrestore.

just so:

```
rrdtool dump my.rrd > file.xml

./rrdAddDS.pl file.xml newDsName > new_file.xml

rrdtool restore new_file.xml my_new.rrd
```

you can refer from here:
http://osdir.com/ml/db.rrdtool.user/2003-08/msg00115.html

and here:
http://www.docum.org/drupal/sites/default/files/add_ds_to_rrd.pl_.txt

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PNP4Nagios (https://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/start), they provide a utility script *rrd_modify.pl* for modifying existing RRD data files.

```
    $ rrd_modify.pl -h

   === rrd_modify.pl 0.01 ===
   Copyright (c) 2012 PNP4Nagios Developer Team (http://www.pnp4nagios.org)

   This script can be used to alter the number of data sources of an RRD file.

   Usage:
   rrd_modify.pl RRD_file insert|delete start_ds[,no_of_cols] [type]

   Arguments:
   RRD_file
      the location of the RRD file. It will NOT be overwritten but appended
      by ".chg"
   insert or delete
      the operation to be executed
   start_ds
      the position at which the operation starts (1..no of data sources+1)
   no_of_cols
      (an optional) number of columns which will be added/deleted
   type
      the data type (one of GAUGE, COUNTER)
                Defaults to GAUGE if not specified for insert operations
        (DERIVE, ABSOLUTE, COMPUTE have not been tested and might result in
                 errors during creation of a new RRD file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.5 `rrdtool create` can "pre-fill" the data from existing file(s) with the `--source` option. This feature solves the problem without the need of additional scripts.

SEE ALSO: Matija Nalis' comment below.

Comment: Even easier, you can use `rrdtool tune my.rrd DS:ds_name:GAUGE:900:-50:100` to simply add data sources to existing .rrd file, while preserving old structure and data.