# Adding new datasources to an existing .rrd

Tags: datasource, rrdtool, gauge, rrd

I have a .rrd db which is collecting data from a temperature gauge. Now I have a second gauge so I'd like to add this new gauge to the existing .rrd database. I tried many times with the "rrdtool tune" command, but after that I run a "rrdtool info" on my database, and I see that there's not the last data source (another gauge) that I tried to insert.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding new datasource to an existing RRD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476226/adding-new-datasource-to-an-existing-rrd)

Answer (score 0):

The command you need is, as you say, `rrdtool tune`.  The documentation is available online at https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdtune.en.html

The ability to extend an RRA and to add or remove a DS was only added late in RRDTool 1.4.  Check that you are not using an older version of RRDTool, as if you are, you will not be able to use this feature until you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, and I see I'm using RRDTOOL 1.4 so I would not have problems. Anyway, the fact is that I used this command:

```
/usr/bin/rrdtool tune TEMPCucina.rrd DS:METEOTEMPEXT:GAUGE:1200:U:U RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:180000
```

I got this back from the computer:

```
DS[TEMPCucina] typ: GAUGE   hbt: 1200   min: nan    max: nan
```

But it seems that I'm not able to write into TEMPCucina.rrd
And if I try to perform the following command:

```
rrdtool info TEMPCucina.rrd
```

I just get the following, and it seems that no new gauge has been created

```
filename = "TEMPCucina.rrd"
rrd_version = "0003"
step = 60
last_update = 1510780261
header_size = 556
ds[TEMPCucina].index = 0
ds[TEMPCucina].type = "GAUGE"
ds[TEMPCucina].minimal_heartbeat = 1200
ds[TEMPCucina].min = NaN
ds[TEMPCucina].max = NaN
ds[TEMPCucina].last_ds = "18"
ds[TEMPCucina].value = 1,8000000000e+01
ds[TEMPCucina].unknown_sec = 0
rra[0].cf = "AVERAGE"
rra[0].rows = 30000
rra[0].cur_row = 1304
rra[0].pdp_per_row = 1
rra[0].xff = 0,0000000000e+00
rra[0].cdp_prep[0].value = NaN
rra[0].cdp_prep[0].unknown_datapoints = 0
```

(when I try to write I get this, but I don't know how to proceed at this point)

```
ERROR: TEMPCucina.rrd: illegal attempt to update using time 1510780527 when last update time is 1510780527 (minimum one second step)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it, but I wasn't able to use the **rrdtool tune** function.

I finally found [here](https://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=4307) how to perform a dump of the database, how to modify it, and finally restore it to its original location (so I could also correct some data).

This is not what I was searching for, but it solved my problem so I want to share it.